# What is the regex pattern for comma-separated list?

Tags: php, regex

Sometimes I need to make sure some input is comma-separated (or whatever-separated) list of well-structured piece of data. In the real world I needed, for example, to validate this kind of format: `foo{bar:baz,abc:def},xyz,lol{rotfl:true}`, which is comma-separated list of strings with or without arguments list (which are comma-separated too). This example is more complicated, I just mention that to prevent you guys from giving banal answers like:

> Why can't you just use explode()?

Which I always get whenever I want to know something about regex better.

For the sake of simplicity, I will use another example. But please remember: this is not actual problem! It's a simplified example of more complex use cases, where I indeed must use regex.

Let's say I need a regex pattern to make sure my string is a list of comma-separated zip codes. Each zip code has format `xx-xxx`, where `x` is any number from 0 to 9 and there is at least one zip code. The list needs to be properly comma-separated, which means:

1. No leading comma
2. No trailing comma
3. No more than one consecutive commas

Normally, I'd do something like this:

```
$pattern = '#^\d{2}-\d{3}(?:,\d{2}-\d{3})*$#';
```

That will work. Is there any way to prevent repeating the `\d{2}-\d{3}` part of the pattern? Of course, I can save it to the variable like this:

```
$zipCodePattern = '\d{2}-\d{3}';
$pattern        = "#^$zipCodePattern(?:,$zipCodePattern)*$#";
```

Although, I'm more than curious if that can be done in the pattern itself.

Comment: Is using `explode()` out of the question?

Comment: Correct. It's hella out.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: It is because I'm curious if any part of the pattern can be repeated that way. I had several situations in my career where I needed such a pattern.

Comment: @Scuzzy your pattern allows trailing comma.

Comment: `\numberHere` is used to match a subpattern. `\1` matches first `()`.

Comment: @PHPglue I don't think it's relevant here. It will match the value, not the pattern. So for example: `#^(\d{2}-\d{3})(?:,\1)*$#` will match `11-111,11-111`, but not `11-111,22-222`.

Comment: Yeah, that would not work in your case. You could use a variable, but it's so little code anyways. If that regex your using is working for you, we should close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
^(\d{2}-\d{3}\b(,(?!$))?)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/7

Comment: Exactly, I just found it out too!

Comment: It's a little hacky, but I guess that's the best that can be done with regex.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `+` to match zip codes between one and unlimited times. Inside the non-capturing group, `(?:,|$)`only allows to match the group with no delimiter if it is the end of the string, making it work if there is only one code in the list. Lastly, a negative look-behind is used to make sure there is no trailing delimiter.

```
^(?:\d{2}-\d{3}(?:,|$))+(?<!,)$
```

Comment: It works as expected, but I feel like I'd like to prevent repeating comma in the pattern too. Is that possible? :) I'm asking for educational purposes too.

Comment: It does prevent repeating commas. For example, `12-123,,12-123` does not match for me. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean repeating comma in the pattern itself. I feel like there might be some way to declare the separator only once in the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to solve this problem is by using the `implode()` or `explode()` functions for this. Is there a reason you want to do this with regex?

Comment: Dear Stack Overflow, YES, I'M SURE. Why is this question raised every time a regex question is posted? Maybe I just want to learn?

Comment: You give us a problem. We try to give you the best solution we know. Sorry for trying.

Comment: I don't give you a problem. I give you a question. There is some faulty logic common here. I know there are some questions that assume wrong solution. I don't even raise any use-case here, this is linguistic question.

Comment: Okay. I am sorry. Maybe I'm just pissed of the full caps usage there. To answer your question: no, I don't think you can write your regex without repeating that pattern.

Comment: Hmm. I see. I think I would prefer the repeating one because it's easier to understand what's happening

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. I explained why it's a big deal.

Comment: I see. Well, as far as I can see RomanPerekhrest has answered your question ;)

Comment: Yeah, I selected it. Do you have any suggestion how can I articulate the question when I just want to learn some good habits? People tend to answer with some "whatever, just make it work by blah blah", but it's not satisfying for me. Giving complex examples is bad, but as it turns out, giving simple ones is bad too.

Comment: Hmm. I think you get answers like that because there are some people out there who really forget the explode function. But maybe if you explicitly say something about it. Like you did in your updated version of the question. Something like `I know I can accomplish this with explode but I want to do it with regex`. But maybe you said that already and I didn't see it

Comment: I added it now. I think you are right. I tend to give very simple examples (because I believe they are the best) and people assume I'm a noob. Then, they think I don't know what I'm doing and put me on the shelf with people using regex for doing something too simple for regex. I'm looking for an answer about the language feature itself, because I have enough experience to know what I'm doing, but people assume I just need a solution to that simple example...